# Fade animation on Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, animation

To preface, there are many questions that ask about fade animations, but none that seem to have my exact problem. I have a Floating Action Button in my application that I would like to fade out with a certain duration and delay. The code for the animation (which even though it shouldn't matter, is inside the floating action action listener) looks like this. In this piece of code, `b` is the FAB.

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
animation1.setDuration(1000);
animation1.setStartOffset(1000);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
b.startAnimation(animation1);
```

The code looks fine, but it just doesn't work, and I'm all out of ideas. I have tried using `b.setAnimation()` in accordance with `b.animate()`, but to no avail. I **do not** want to use XML, for the value of the animation startOffSet relies on other components.

Thanks in advance.

*** **UPDATE** ***

I've found a fix. instead of `b.startAnimation(animation)`, apply the animation to the button: `b.setAnimation(animation)`. If you then try to make the button/view invisible like so

```
b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBILE)
```

It will use the animation you specified.

Comment: Try using the `nineolddroids` library; usually it magically fixes animation problems like these (the "it just doesn't work" problems)

Comment: A magical fix is what I need right about now. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it out.

Comment: First of all, check if the default hide() method on FloatingActionButton works for you. This is a standard way to make the FAB disappear.

Answer (score 4):

Can you please specify which android support design library version you are using? 
I tested the below code on **23.2.0** and animation is being performed just fine using below code:

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            animation1.setDuration(1000);
            animation1.setStartOffset(1000);
            animation1.setFillAfter(true);
            fab.startAnimation(animation1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rafay. I have already found a solution however (see main post) :). I was using version 23.1.1.